# Power BI service, disable download of Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have published reports from Power BI desktop to Power BI service.
I want the users to be able to do their own analysis with the datasets/data model **BUT** I don't want them to have the ability to download the .pbix file.

Note: I am not using premium capacity.
I have tried the permissions as well. If the user is a "Viewer" then they cannot access the datasets.
If they are members and contributor then yes they can access the data set, but are also able to download the .pbix file which is what I don't want them to do.

Comment: I would check out the Power BI Admin Portal, if you have access, you can turn off this option

Comment: @Matrix007 is this sorted?

Comment: I can get to admin portable under Power BI but not under the o365. I am using a Company account. I will need to wait till Jan until our IT dept is back.

Comment: If I disable the export data function then the users are unable to their own analysis, therefore it does not solve my challenge.I want the users to be able to do their own analysis with the datasets/data model BUT i don't want them to have the ability to download the .pbix file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

The only option is to disable "Export data" option under [Admin Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-portal#tenant-settings).

Turning off this option will prevent the whole organization from Exporting data to Excel/CSV , as well as Downloading PBIX file.

The admin portal is accessible to all users who are Global Admins in Office 365 or have been assigned the Power BI service administrator role.

**Option 2**

Are the members of the O365 group set as members or admins in your app?  I had the same issue with one of my reports and changing the users in the group to members took away their ability to download the report as a .pbix.

You can check this by going to the Edit Workspace (same place you set Members can only view Power BI content) and checking the list of users.  Each user should have either Admin or Member next to their name.  If you do not want the user to have the capability to download the file, you should set them as a member.

Comment: If I disable the export data function then the users are unable to their own analysis, therefore it does not solve my challenge.I want the users to be able to do their own analysis with the datasets/data model BUT i don't want them to have the ability to download the .pbix file.

Comment: @Matrix007 i edit my answer with option 2. Check it and let me know status.

Comment: I have tried to change my users to member in the edit workspace. Yes it stops them to download but then it also takes away the ability to edit the report and access to the fields. I want them to be able to access the fields so that they can do their own analysis but not be able to download the .pbix.

Comment: @Matrix007 can you post your issue in here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/idb-p/Issues or here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/free/ . Currently i'm thinking this is a limitation in power bi, so they might able to help you.

Comment: I have posted. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/How-to-allow-interaction-with-data-BUT-not-download-pbix/idi-p/902816#M52736,  thank you. Will let you know if we find a solution

Comment: No, it does not work and I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Matrix007 please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-datasets-build-permissions

Comment: This is fantastic and it worked. I have tried this in the past and looks like there has been some recent changes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your report from Power BI Desktop, publish it in your "My Workspace", rather than other workspaces where your audience has access to.
This allows your audience to view your dashboard/report, but they don't have the option to "download pbix file".  Please see if this option works for you, it's working for me.
Please note, your audience still has ability to "Analyze in Excel" with "Build Permission".

Answer (score 1):

the tenant admin can disable the ability to download .pbix files and paginated reports in **Admin portal > Export and sharing settings > Download Reports**

it can be applied to the entire org or specific security groups. please see the screenshot attached for details

[image]